# What can I do with killer bees?

Tags: dont-starve

It doesn't look like killer bees are good for crafting a bee box out of them. They don't turn neutral either, so I wonder how I could put captured killer bees to use without getting killed in the process.

Comment: Are you referring to how to kill them or how to utilize them for crafting purposes?

Comment: In the words of a Cards Against Humanity card: Bees?

Comment: In the words of Nicholas Cage: "NOT THE BEES!"

Comment: "Or what? Are you gonna release the hounds, or the bees, or the hounds with bees in their mouths so everytime they bark at you they shoot bees at you? Go ahead, do your worst." - Homer Simpson

Comment: The hounds are not too fond of bees themselves, as it turns out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to deal with killer bees without losing significant health and still getting the resources that come from killing them:

First, the easiest way to defeat Killer Bees is to use a Bug Net. Using the net will turn the Bee into an item in your inventory. Killer Bees caught this way can't be used to make bee mines or bee boxes. What you can do is murder it without removing it from your inventory. The way to do this is to mouse over it. You will see the "Murder" command pop up once you do so. Click the right mouse button and it will kill the bee without removing it from your inventory. This will result in a crafting material like a stinger or honey sitting in the place where it used to be in your inventory. This way, you can use the bee for certain crafting recipes.

Second, you could craft a bee catchers helmet. When wearing it, you will take minimal damage from killer bees so even if they manage to hit you a couple of times before you kill it, it wouldn't be a serious blow to your health. Once it dies it will drop a crafting object that can be used in recipes.

Comment: Right, I can just **murder** killer bees inside my inventory and get the loot!

Comment: And this is why the bees are disappearing. Thanks Arqade.

Comment: Bug net/helmet is the way to go with killer bees. I had a fun alternative in the adventure mode killer bee island once, where a hound mound was close enough to the killer bees... let them duck it out, collect the honey, destroy the hive while they are distracted...

Answer (score 4):

Killer bees can be put inside Chester, who can then be treacherously left to die among your enemies. The agonizing rage of killer bees will surely vanquish the unsuspecting attackers creating loot with a side bonus of some stingers and, possibly, honey from dead killer bees. The remaining bees can be recaptured. Chester will reappear unharmed after a day, ready to be left for dead yet again.

Or you can simply drop the killer bees on the ground in the middle of your enemies. Bees will take a quick nap, long enough for you to get away, and then wake up to seek prey.

It's much more useful and fun than just killing killer bees yourself.

Comment: So, what happens, he dies, and drops the Killer Bees?  Can they attack you still?  And, how are you getting Chester to do this?  Dropping the Eye Bone?

Comment: Chester follows you, but doesn't start moving towards you unless he's in a certain maximum range (half screen). You can make him follow you into aggro range of all-hostile creatures and simply wait for his demise. You don't have to, but you can drop the eyebone if you wish to keep away from danger.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post from a dev](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/32359-killer-bees-spawning-in-place-of-bumblebees-in-spring-pollinating-flowers/?page=0#comment-430986), in the Reign of Giants expansion, killer bees can be used for crafting during some parts of the year provided you have encountered them in the wild and not caused them to spawn from a hive.

Following is a copy of his response:

> > I think the problem is that killer bees are not valid for beeboxes or bee mines (I think, haven't checked in a while) and the bumblebees now
> >     look identical
>
> Yeah, this is definitely something we considered. Ultimately, we
>   decided that we preferred the slight inconsistency of a red Spring bee
>   turning into a yellow bee when you catch it to not having this
>   mechanic at all.
>
> > 2) Can we use the red spring bees as bee ingredients for boxes and mines?  That was actually what prompted me to check here; I was all
> >     psyched up to make a bee box when spring came, and all I saw were red
> >     bees.   As I said above, red spring bees will revert to normal yellow
> >     bees when you catch them. So, yes, you can use them in those recipes.
>
> As for telling them apart (i.e. for knowing that a bee you're trying
>   to catch is valid for a recipe), the rule that actual killer bees
>   won't spawn unless you start attacking the bees/beehives is still in
>   place. So, if you happen upon a bee in the world and you haven't
>   attacked any bees or beehives, that's a normal bee for crafting
>   purposes, regardless of its color.
>
> > I think the problem is that killer bees are not valid for beeboxes or bee mines (I think, haven't checked in a while) and the bumblebees
> >     now look identical   Yeah, this is definitely something we considered.
> >     Ultimately, we decided that we preferred the slight inconsistency of a
> >     red Spring bee turning into a yellow bee when you catch it to not
> >     having this mechanic at all.
>
> On 3/13/2014 at 2:21 PM, Zalyn said: 2) Can we use the red spring
>   bees as bee ingredients for boxes and mines?  That was actually what
>   prompted me to check here; I was all psyched up to make a bee box when
>   spring came, and all I saw were red bees.
>
> As I said above, red spring bees will revert to normal yellow bees
>   when you catch them. So, yes, you can use them in those recipes.
>
> As for telling them apart (i.e. for knowing that a bee you're trying
>   to catch is valid for a recipe), the rule that actual killer bees
>   won't spawn unless you start attacking the bees/beehives is still in
>   place. So, if you happen upon a bee in the world and you haven't
>   attacked any bees or beehives, that's a normal bee for crafting
>   purposes, regardless of its color.

Comment: could you cite the post here? you know, link rot, etc

Comment: fair point, it is done

Comment: Sorry, you're confusing two things: when you attack a bee box, a red killer bee comes out. The red killer bee can be caught, but can not be used for crafting. Now, in Reign Of Giants, spring bees also became aggressive and they were also red. When you caught them, they reverted to yellow and could be crafted. The dev's response is talking about that. What does not change: **a killer bee can never be used for crafting**.

Comment: I'm confusing things? I'm quoting a dev.